# Axios MySql DELETE/UPDATE not working or providing error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to use Axios with Node.Js to make a delete request in a MySql table and I'm unsure what's going wrong. Despite the error catch console.log I'm not getting any errors in console. What's wrong here? The MySql table is working for INSERT, SELECT, and GET.

This is where I call the request:

```
let para1 = document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML;
let para2 = document.getElementById("para2").innerHTML;
let para3 = document.getElementById("para3").innerHTML;
Axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/delete', {col1: para1, col2: para2, col3: para3}) 
                .then(()=>{});         
window.location.reload();
```

In terms of the Axios/Node backend code this is what is executing:

```
app.delete('/delete', (req, res)=>{
    const para1 = req.body.col1;
    const para2 = req.body.col2;
    const para3 = req.body.col3;
    db.query('DELETE FROM exampleTable WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?', [para1, para2, para3], (err, result)=>{if(err){console.log(err);}else{console.log("Done!");}});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` requests generally should not have a request body (like `GET`). It's highly likely that something strips the body.

Don't rely on this. The only thing that a `DELETE` request should delete, is the *thing* identified in the URL. It never makes sense to "delete `/delete`", because after "deleting `/delete`", the `/delete` resource should no longer exist. I hope that's not too confusing.

In other words, this makes sense:

```
DELETE /article/123
DELETE /folder/pictures
```

But this does not:

```
DELETE /delete
```

You are basically building an RPC-style API, so just use `POST`.

Comment: I changed the axios request from app.delete to app.post and nothing changed.

Comment: You need to provide more information then. You should also handle errors from `db.query`, it looks right now you just ignore the result.